# JSTL error javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTag error when using c:forEach tomcat ver7.0

Tags: tomcat, foreach, jstl, runtime-error

Hi using 
eclipse juno, dynamic web project
apache Tomcat v7.0 (which has its own jstl-1.2.1.jar) 
I get this error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTag
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:343)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

when I try running this jsp code

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<c:forEach var="test" items="a,b,c">
${test}
</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

it seams not to be seeing the javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTag class that is in the jar
I have read something about filters blocking javax.servlet files 

any help would be greatly appreciated

---

ok I think I have found the solution
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
does not contain the javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core classes

jstl-1.2.jar needs to be added as well

Comment: ound the solution
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar<br />
does not contain the javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core classes<br />

jstl-1.2.jar needs to be added as well

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Added [jstl-1.2.jar](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2) to Tomcat's library fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 7):

`javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar` doesn't contain the `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core` classes. Be sure to add [`jstl-1.2.jar`](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2) as well.

Comment: Why does MVNRepository [say](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2) `jstl:jstl` have been moved to `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jstl`, if the new jar doesn't contain `.core`?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using maven, add

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use forEach you should add two libraries to WEB-INF/lib of your project:
Impl:
taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
Spec:
taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar

Answer (score 0):

I imported "taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar" I downloaded from http://tomcat.apache.org/download-taglibs.cgi and I encountered the same error.
I tried importing "jstl-1.2.jar" as Limited Atonement suggested before and it worked.
So I compared those two jars:

- "jstl-1.2.jar" contains 3 folders: "javax", "META-INF" and "org".
- "taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar" contains only 2 folders: "META-INF"
  and "org".

So I tried swch's suggestion. I removed jstl-1.2.jar and importing both "taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar" and "taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar".

This solved the issue, because the "spec" lib contains the "javax" folder which contains the required classes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, using conditional tag <c:if>.
I was only using
taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar.

After downloading the jstl.jar from [jstl.jar download page](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjstljar.htm) and adding it to Tomcat's installation lib directory it works.