# Java JSTL Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTag

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jstl

My project has the following error when I use the JSTL `c:forEach` tag. I'm using apache `Tomcat v7.0`.

I added the following jars in the `WEB-INF\lib` folder.

1. taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5
2. taglibs-standard-jstlel-1.2.5

**Error**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTag
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
...
```

**My jsp file login.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="10" step="1">
        <c:out value="${i}" />
    </c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSTL error javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTag error when using c:forEach tomcat ver7.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693969/jstl-error-javax-servlet-jsp-jstl-core-looptag-error-when-using-cforeach-tomcat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar`.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue though, still looking for solutions :(